# Can I check if a YAML file has been updated before loading it into Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have a YAML file that loads in a set of questions to my rails DB. Occasionally I'm making changes to the Question.yml file (e.g. I might want to change the question text slightly), and due to the way I'm loading these into a rails Question model, the DB rejects the update (because there's already a Question in my DB with that id). I'm making more frequent changes to the questions at the moment and want it to be more flexible, so can I check the YAML file before uploading it to see if, e.g. the last saved time has changed, then only actually update the DB if this has happened?

An example question:

```
- id: 1
  question_text: Why does this company need to buy your products or services?
  answer_type: Text Field
  next_question_id_yes: 2
  next_question_id_no: ~
  collectable: ~
  sale_stage: Need
```

How the file is currently loaded into the DB:

```
File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/questions.yml", 'r') do |file|
   YAML::load(file).each do |record|
    Question.create(record) unless Question.exists?(record)
   end
end
```

This method is quick to check if the record already exists (as the exists? method only checks the id of the question), but useless as I'm not changing the question id's - only the other fields below in the DB. As you can see I need the id's to remain static because this forms part of a decision tree and each question needs to know which question id follows it (depending on the answer_type and answer provided).

Currently when I try to update the YAML file and then use that in the app I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "questions_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "questions" ("answer_type", "created_at", "id", "next_question_id_yes", "question_text", "sale_stage", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"
```

Is there some way I can store the status of the YAML file itself, and if it has been updated then I can just destroy all the old records and upload the new YAML file as gospel?

P.S. If this is a stupid idea for some reason I can't think of, please also let me know. It seems somewhat wasteful of resources, but I expect to add more questions and to update them for users in future, so I need this flexibility without having to manually do this in the rails console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by)

```
File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/questions.yml", 'r') do |file|
   YAML::load(file).deep_symbolize_keys.each do |record|
     q = Question.find_or_initialize_by(id: record[:id]))
     q.assign_attributes( record.except(:id) ) 
     q.save! if q.new_record? || q.changed?    
   end
end
```

Although in the long run its probably a lot easier to just create a basic CRUD controller so that you can edit the records via a GUI (or get an intern to do it)...

Comment: Thanks - however the line `q.save! if q.new_record? || q.changed?` is still throwing the same duplicate key value error. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hmm, does `q = Question.find_or_initialize_by(id: record[:id]))` find a record?

Comment: Also hardcoding the ID's into your YAML file can be somewhat risky as ID's are generated by the database.

Comment: Thanks @max - that was where it went wrong. I've used `r = record.symbolize_keys
i_d = 'id'
rid = r[i_d.to_sym] ques = Question.find_or_initialize_by(id: rid)`

Comment: I've marked this as the right answer in any case - feel free to update the original with the code there. I know hard-coding the id's is not the best idea, but I figured it was senseless to create another column to do this, as the fact it falls over when I try to duplicate an id is a useful sanity check for me.

Comment: Forgot about the fact that `YAML::load` does not symbolize the keys - good catch.